# Variance of white noise filtered by a zero-mean sum.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given a function $s$, I have the following property on the sum:

$$
\sum_i^n \left[ s(i) \times s'(i) \right] = 0.
$$

The function $s$ is continuous and bounded by $A$:
$$
\left|s(i)\right| \leq A \; \forall i \in [0 .. n]
$$

The derivative of $s'$ is also continuous and bounded by $M$:

$$
\left|s'(i)\right| \leq M \; \forall i \in [0 .. n]
$$

And now I add some **uncorrelated** white noise distribution $\delta_i$ in the sum. We have the variance $\text{Var}(\delta_i) = \sigma^2$ and mean $E(\delta_i) = 0$.

So
$$
\text{Var}\left(\sum_i^n \delta_i\right) = n\sigma^2.
$$

I would like now to calculate the variance of the sum with the $\delta_i$ :
$$\text{Var}\left( \sum_i^n \left[ s(i) \times s'(i) \times \delta_i\right]\right),$$
or find a good upper bound to the sum. Do you have any suggestion?

---

The best I can think of is the trivial bound which doesn't use the sum=0 property:

$$\text{Var}\left( \sum_i^n \left[ s(i) \times s'(i) \times \delta_i\right]\right) \leq nA^2M^2\sigma^2$$

Comment: This is unreadable. Please explain $s_i$, $\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)_i$, $s(i)$, and $\frac{ds}{dt_i}$.

Comment: @Did right my notations were a mess. Is this better

Comment: Yes. Now it seems clear that the "trivial" upper bound is in fact reached--so how to improve it?

Comment: No I don't this it can be reached. If $s(i)=A$ then $s'(i)=0$ because $A$ is the maximum value of $s$.

Comment: Not reached as a maximum but such that no smaller value is an upper bound (if $n$ is even choose $s$ such that $s(i)=A-\varepsilon$ and $s'(i)=\pm M$).